# query to get distinct data from child table

Tags: mysql

please provide query to getting my result.

i have two tables as follows.

```
price_band

id  club_id  name  price
1      6     test   2.3
2      6     test1  3.3

price_band_seat

id  price_band_id  row seat  block_id
1     1              a   1      1
2     1              a   2      1
3     1              b   1      2
4     2              b   2      2

and result that i want 

Price  block_id  price_band_id  row 
2.3       1            1         a
2.3       2            1         b
3.3       2            2         b
```

query exclude that raw which block_id and price_band_id  are same . in where clues you have to take club_id=6

Comment: _"please provide query"_ - That's not how this site works. SO is not a free coding service. You need to make some proper attempts to solve the issue yourself first. Then, if you're running into some specific issue with your existing code, we can help you sort that out. But that means that you need to post your attempts.

Comment: You should also make sure to add _relevant_ tags. The question is a pure SQL-question so you should remove the php, mysqli and phpmyadmin tag (since they aren't directly involved in the issue)

Comment: in row1 of your result block_id and price_band_id are same .

Comment: @MagnusEriksson SELECT 
  `pricing_band_seats`.*,
  `price`,
  `display_name`,
  DISTINCT `pricing_bands`.`id` AS `pricingBandId` 
FROM
  `pricing_band_seats` 
  INNER JOIN `pricing_bands` 
    ON `pricing_bands`.`id` = `pricing_band_seats`.`pricing_band_id` 
WHERE `club_id` = 6

Comment: @Deepak not a duplicate row in result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT 
  A.Price,B.block_id,B.price_band_id,B.row 
FROM 
    price_band A
INNER JOIN price_band_seat B 
ON A.id = B.price_band_id
WHERE A.club_id = 6
```

Comment: Is it your table name price_band or anything else ?